# Hide the green pivot point

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've been trying to hide the green pivot point that is displayed by default when navigating with the orbit tool, but cannot seem to get rid of it.

I already tried

```
viewer.utilities.pivotActive(false)
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `viewer.navigation.setPivotSetFlag(false)`